# Is this what English/Mandarin Chinese or other 21st century dominant langauges would eventually do too? (details below)(yup that's opinion based)

Tags: historical-linguistics, language-change, sociolinguistics, philosophy-of-language, evolution

*Umbrians, for example, continued to make inscriptions in their language for centuries after Roman annexation. But eventually the power and status of Latin prevailed, particularly after all residents of Italy became Roman citizens in the middle of the last century bc. At ﬁrst other groups would just have used Latin for “outside” purposes, but gradually the centralizing power of Rome “relegated the local speech, just as it did political initiative and concerns, to a secondary, subordinate, and ever retreating position.” We do not know exactly when the last speakers of Oscan, Umbrian, Etruscan, and other languages of the peninsula ﬁnally passed away, but the elimination of all non-Latin languages from the Italian peninsula is likely to have been almost complete by the time Herod washed his hands of another death in another part of the Roman Empire.* **-Nick Evans, Dying Words**

Will penetration of world-dominating languages, start making hollow the not so dominant ones around them (not, though, in this way, but in a morphed one)?

Comment: Downvoter, give a reason as to why you put a downvote over there at least.

Comment: Not the Downvoter but two thoughts, we have and will have alot more translation possibilities, so it is and will not be necessary to write in a dominant language to reach a wider audience. Second, there is no central language authority for English at least, so the language is could and will change and create new languages, e.g. Singlish

Comment: @AlternativeTransport: We also have Esperanto.

Comment: @AlternativeTransport Yeah exactly, but my point being, English through technocracy, MNCs or by other means seeped in Hindi too, thus creating Hinglish (widely used, growing and being researched) , which by any means is using more and more English and in a few decades -if not years- will _take over_ , which is exactly what I thought of when reading through the book and then your comment, good thoughts though :) Thanks!

Comment: @AlternativeTransport Hehe, *Not the Downvoter*.

Comment: I don't think that you can apply the same situation, political domination is the most leading factor there. There are always been lingua franca through the ages. I don't think that we will have the same situation with mandarin or english (unless China begins to invade countries). Even in Hindi case, the reason is British invasion, and their politics in india (cultural, educational enforcement etc.)

Comment: @kabraxis vote counted! though, please refer to my above comment, I am trying to ask, if the present scenario would be a morphed case of the earlier one?

Comment: The guy washing hands would be Pilate, not Herod.

Comment: @LuísHenrique I am intrigued.

Comment: Doubtful. Greeks, Slavs, Armenians, Georgians, and Jews were/are not unaware of the Latin alphabet, but did not abandon their own ancestral scripts.